# Is there a c# design pattern for chaining producer/consumer?

Tags: c#, consumer, chain, producer

this is my first ever post on Stack Overflow.

I am trying to create a C# console application that handles web requests which essentially consists of three steps:

1. Read input lines from a file (which can have a length of several million lines).
2. Each line is seperately fed into a Web API where I await the request, do some interpretation of the response and generate x new lines per input. This step is done through a proxy network of a variable number of different proxies (each proxy corresponding to a single `HttpClient` ).
3. All x lines per input are written into the same output file.

I've read about the Producer/Consumer pattern using channels which really comes with a lot of interesting options (limit the channel size, enable multithreading, etc.). I have to run this script on an old computer with few RAM, so I want to prevent any type of memory overflow (such as lists or queues that are written faster than executed).

My design idea was to make the input file reader a single producer, which feeds data into the channel. The consumers (one for each `HttpClient`) then takes the data and processes it through the API. But I would need an additional consumer (writer to output file).

I don't think this is what Producer/Consumer pattern is for. Is there another way to chain these types of dataflow? I've also thought about adding a simple `BlockingCollection` or `ConcurrentQeue` at the end, but my guess is that they would not communicate with the producers and don't tell them to await a certain size.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you want a [Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) Pipeline.

Comment: And welcome to SO. Well done first question, by the way!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I'll have a look at dataflow, but a quick question already: data flow blocks can be executed parallel? Means that step 2 (API request) has for example 50 instances running at the same time which kind of "consume" the data from step 1 (file read)?

Comment: You can can fan out and join results, yes. Although I think 50 concurrent requests may be too many especially on an old machine. But you will need to play around with the details anyway. Each block can have a specific setting of desired concurrency level.

Comment: Agreed; TPL Dataflow is likely the best fit for what you need. Set `BoundedCapacity` on every block and `PropagateCompletion` on every link, and then you can play with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` as desired.

Comment: `System.Threading.Channels` is another possibility, but it's a bit lower-level. There's no concept of producers or consumers within that library - a channel is just the queue between them. So anything like completion propagation or concurrency/parallelism needs to be done yourself.